# Give file permissions back to root

Tags: 14.04, command-line, permissions

I accidentally typed out this command, not knowing exactly what it did:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /
```

Now when I type `ls -la /`, it shows that user has permission to all directories (before it showed root only).

How do I revert it back to root?

Answer (score 0):

This is messed up very badly.

For starters:

```bsh
cd /
chown root:root -R bin boot cdrom etc initrd.img* lib lib64 lost+found mnt opt root  run sbin srv tmp usr var vmlinuz*  
# essentially everything except home and media
chown root:root home media # we don't want to recursively chown here.
```

I assume you have a root shell open somewhere. If not, try `pkexec chown`, since `sudo` won't work when `/etc/sudoers` has incorrect permissions/owners.

Then there are various folders in `/var` whose correct owners you'll have to set, but that depends on which programs you have installed and which services you need to run.

If you're not able to run a command, or some other errors happen, try this from a bootable live USB (after mounting the root partition somewhere and replacing `cd /` with the path of the mount point).

Note that I have skipped a few directories, such as `sys`, `proc`, as these are directories populated by the kernel.